# regular expression that match variable names not begining with #, $,

Tags: regex, delphi

i'm working with Delphi, i need to create a regular expression that captures  variable names and function names in a formula. the names start with a letter `[a-zA-Z]` followed by any character `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

the regular expression is this: `\b[a-zA-Z]\w+\b`

it works fine, the only problem is that it also captures variable names which start with `$` or `#` or dot (`.`) and i don't want that.

Comment: Can we assume, that you use `TRegex`? Or are do you mean the IDE-regex?

Comment: Show the strings which are working and not working

Answer (score 2):

Assuming variables that start with `$` `#` or (`.`) are the only things you need to avoid, you could try something like this.

```
\b(?<!(#|\$|\.))[a-zA-Z]\w+\b
```

This uses your first regex, and will match all words that do not have the prefix of `$` or `#` or (`.`).

Comment: To capture single character identifiers too, I guess `\w*` should be used. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a negative lookbehind to assert that what is before is not a non whitespace character:

`(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]\w+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NVDID6/1)

Note that `\w` also matches an underscore instead of only `[a-zA-Z0-9]`